# Arducam ESP32S Uno Pinout

Tags: arduino, pins, esp32, lora

I am trying to attempt to hook up an [Adafruit Lora RFM9X](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-rfm69hcw-and-rfm96-rfm95-rfm98-lora-packet-padio-breakouts) to an [Arducam ESP32-S Uno](https://www.arducam.com/product/b0105-arducam-esp32-uno-board-for-arducam-mini-camera-module-compatible-with-arduino-uno-r3/) board. However, I am receiving the following error:

Failed to put device in Lora Mode RH_RF95_REG_01_OP_MODE: 0

I believe this error is coming from a pin layout error when hooking up the wiring between the ESP and the Lora. More specifically, I believe the error may be coming from the placement of hardware interrupt pin. Does anyone have any familiarity with the Arducam board and could offer some assistance?